# How to pimp a cheap power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm building a small class D amplifier: some op amp circuits for pre-amplification, a pwm modulator based on a dsPIC, some power buffers for controlling the gates of an h-bridge power stage, and a LC output filter.

To power the system I bought a cheap (7€) power supply 12V, 5A. A photo below to give the idea of the device:
[image]

I tested it and it seems quite strong: while increasing the current flow the voltage always remained at a fixed value.

The problem is that every 15us there is a very high frequency oscillation (~1MHz, ~2V amplitude) on the output. Images below:

[image]

To reduce the output of these pulses i tried:

- An additional LC filter (L=200uH, C=30uF tantalum) on the output. The ripple still remains and I don't know why.
- A 12v standard zener regulator. The ripple still remains (maybe because the frequency is too high for a zener diode???)

What else do you recommend to do?

Thanks

Comment: how are you probing your psu? maybe its radiated noise, not conducted

Comment: @Wesley Lee I don't think it is radiated noise because it is not a constant sine waveform but is an oscillation that happens every 15us with a very high frequency and dies in about 500ns. It's like a high frequency heart beat.

Comment: radiated noise does not have to be a sine wave..

Comment: Try putting a load on the output.

Comment: Tantalum capacitors do not work well at high frequencies. Try a ceramic instead. You don't need to be down at fc=2kHz (which may be detrimental to your audio), as you are targeting noise that is around 50MHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your power supply appears to be missing the Y capacitor which will make it more difficult to measure the output noise (the 2V you are seeing is almost surely not real). It does have what look likes a nice common-mode choke and X capacitor(s).

[image]

The purpose of this capacitor is to conduct some of the 67kHz switching noise out to the earth terminal. It must be a safety rated capacitor designed for Y use. Don't just stick any old cap in there- this is a safety issue.

[image: http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnvar/20130521/CL18315]

To get a better measurement, try grounding the supply output to earth and using a differential measurement on the output terminals (A-B with two scope probes). Just grounding the output deliberately (not through the scope probe) should help.

Comment: Thank you @Spehro Pefhany, using an Y1, 1000pF capacitor reduced the noise to 50mVpp. 
Considering that this is a classD power supply, would it be usefull to use an additional LC filter (with very low cut frequency) on the output of the smps?

Comment: Good to hear it made a profound difference in the measured noise. You could consider adding a common mode L-C filter (google common mode choke- something like 1mH and rated for your required current or above) but the switching frequency (and the harmonics) are way above audible so a bit of noise may not have much effect on the quality of sound.

Comment: Ok but, a common mode choke is only for AC (so it should be placed in the 220V AC line), am I right? Would be useful to add an extra LC (with a simple 1-wire-inductor) filter between the output of the smps and the classD circuit?

Comment: You can use a common mode choke equally well on DC!

Comment: Can you please explain me why it would be better to use a common mode choke instead of a standard LC filter? I dont get exactly why someone should use one instead of the other.

Comment: A common mode choke uses two windings one one core that create fields that cancel for your output current (which is differential mode). That allows more common mode inductance for the same size of core without the core saturating. For example, you can probably get 1mH or 1.5mH of series inductance rated at 5A in around 1in^3. Compare with two 2mH 5A inductors and you'll see a very significant difference in size and cost. Of course if you're trying to eliminate differential mode noise then you need the inductance on at least one line.